# Delegation strategy Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and learning closures from [this](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) guide.

> Whenever, in a closure, a property is accessed without explicitly setting a receiver object, then a delegation strategy is involved.

Shouldn't this return `ALLAUDIN`. Where am I doing wrong?

```
class Example {

class Person {
String name
Person(String name){
    this.name = name
}
}

class  Thing {
String name
Thing(String name){
    this.name = name
}
}


static void main(String[] args){
    Example e = new Example();

    def p = new Person(e, 'allaudin')
    def t = new Thing(e, 'laptop')

    def getUpperName = { name.toUpperCase() }
    getUpperName.delegate = p
    println getUpperName() // EXAMPLE

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [delegation strategy](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/groovy-goodness-setting-closures.html)

Add the line:

```
getUpperName.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
```

Where you set the delegate